# Extending Spring StoredProcedure with IN and OUT parameters

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following Oracle PL/SQL call which works perfectly fine:

```
declare
  dummy number;
begin
   my.proc(a => 89561,
           b => 1,
           c => 1,
           d => '',
           e => 1,
           f => 1,
           g => 1,
           h => 1,
           i => 1,
           j => 1,
           k => 1,
           l => 1,
           m => 1,
           n => 1,
           o => 1,
           p => 1,
          q => dummy);
 end;
```

I want to call it programmatically and for this I created a class which extends *org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure*. Class is the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

public class MySP extends StoredProcedure {

    private static final String PROC_NAME = "my.proc";

    public MySP(DataSource ds) {
        super(ds,PROC_NAME);
        compile();
    }

    public void execute() {
        Map<String, Object>  params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("a", 89561L);
        params.put("b", 1L);
        params.put("c", 1L);
        params.put("d", "");
        params.put("e", 1L);
        params.put("f", 1L);
        params.put("g", 1L);
        params.put("h", 1L);
        params.put("i", 1L);
        params.put("j", 1L);
        params.put("k", 1L);
        params.put("l", 1L);
        params.put("m", 1L);
        params.put("n", 1L);
        params.put("o", 1L);
        params.put("p", 1L);
        params.put("q", 0L);
        super.execute(params);
    }
}
```

When I run his code, I'm geting the following Oracle error:

**PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'proc'**

I'm pretty sure the error comes from the way I'm passing the "q" parameter ... but can't find another way of passing it.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring `StoredProcedure` requires you to declare the type of the parameters that you're going to pass. See the example below.

```
public class MySP extends StoredProcedure {
    private static final String PROC_NAME = "my.proc";

    public MySP(DataSource ds) {
        super(ds,PROC_NAME);

        //declaraction of parameters
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("x", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("y", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter("z", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR));
    }
    public void execute() {
        Map<String, Object>  params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("x", 89561L);
        params.put("y", 1L);
        params.put("z", 1L);

        super.execute(params);
    }

}
```