# Spring: JdbcTemplate throws a PLS-00201 while trying to call a stored db function

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have a function inside our oracle database named `GET_ACS_SERVER_AUTH_METHOD_REP`.

This is how I perform the call of the function in the database:

```
public String getAuthReport () throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

        List <SqlParameter> declaredParameters = new ArrayList <SqlParameter>();
        declaredParameters.add(new SqlParameter("start_d", Types.DATE));
        declaredParameters.add(new SqlParameter("end_d", Types.DATE));
        declaredParameters.add(new SqlOutParameter("return", Types.CLOB));

        Map <String, Object> resultMap = jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement (Connection con) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call GET_SERVER_AUTH_METHOD_REP(?, ?, ?)}");
                callableStatement.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-01-01"));
                callableStatement.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2017-06-30"));
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.CLOB);
                return callableStatement;
            }
        }, declaredParameters);
        return "success";
    }
```

This unfortunately doesn't work and returns this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'GET_ACS_SERVER_AUTH_METHOD_REP' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I've asked our DBA if maybe some permissions are missing on my side, but he said no.

Also I've read that there are some bugs with oracle/spring when oracle is version 12.

Maybe somebody encountered something similar and managed to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: is the function compiled correctly?

Comment: @user7294900 yes of course. It works when calling from sql developer.

Comment: can you give the function declaration, it can be variable type issue

Comment: @user7294900 `create or replace FUNCTION get_server_auth_method_rep(start_d DATE, end_d DATE) return CLOB IS`

Comment: Try without spring with plain JDBC, see if that works. That may give you some clues.

Comment: @11thdimension it seems to work in plain JDBC, but that is very depressing. It's like all of sudden realizing that you have to start using a phone booth instead of a cell phone.

Comment: :) , I'm not saying that you should use phone booth, just that using phone booth will give you clues if you're doing something wrong. If it works with plain JDBC, then it rules out the bug with the Oracle that you have noted in the question.

Comment: @11thdimension it could be a bug with spring, but that would make things even more depressing :)

Comment: Try `StoredProcedure`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684169/5343269

Comment: @11thdimension even if it is a function I can still use the `StoredProcedure`?

Comment: I have used it with the PL SQL procedures, it should work with the functions also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that my `DataSource` bean which was passed into the constructor of the class that had the method to call the function in the database was passed with wrong db credentials. I had multiple DataSources and I had to define the correct one to be passed in by using the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If this is definition of your function

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_server_auth_method_rep(start_d DATE, end_d DATE) return CLOB
```

Code should look like this.

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{? = call GET_SERVER_AUTH_METHOD_REP(?,?)}"); 
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.CLOB);
callableStatement.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-01-01"));
callableStatement.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2017-06-30"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also returns the same error... :(